# method that return function in scala unclear syntax

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala but I've been working with Java for a long time now so programming is not new to me. 
Anyway I read a some books on Scala and came across an example that a method returns a function. Now returning a function from method is not new since Java 8 support lambda expression but I can't understand the following example:

```
def lowIt(inputValue: String): Double => Double = {
  if (inputValue == "Lower") x => x * 0.85
  else x => x
}
```

I don't understand where x comes from, I would expect the following:

```
def lowIt(inputValue: String): Double => Double = x => {
   if (inputValue == "Lower") x * 0.85
  else x
}
```

I don't get the first way of writing the above method.
Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite that function like this:

```
def lowIt(inputValue: String): Double => Double = {
  if (inputValue == "Lower") {(x: Double) => x * 0.85 }
  else {(x: Double) => x}
}
```

the 2 return values are functions, and `x` is the input of the function

Comment: you can replace `{(x: Double) => x}` with `identity`

Answer (score 2):

If it seems more intuitive to you, you *could* start with the second version: it behaves the same as the first one. However, if you look at it closely, you will notice that the `inputValue` captured by the closure never changes, so that your function

```
x => { if (inputValue == "Lower") x * 0.85 else x }
```

always takes either the `then`-branch, or the `else`-branch. But then you don't really have to make the `if-else` comparison for every single `x`. Instead, you can make the decision just *once*.

In case that `inputValue == "Lower"` holds, your function becomes

```
x => { if (true) x * 0.85 else x } 
x => x * 0.85
_ * 0.85
```

In the case that `inputValue != "Lower"`, your function is just

```
x => { if (false) x * 0.85 else x }
x => x
identity
```

Thus, starting with your own version, after a few simple rewriting steps, the function is simplified to

```
def lowIt(inputValue: String): Double => Double = {
  if (inputValue == "Lower") x => x * 0.85
  else x => x
}
```

or even shorter:

```
def lowIt(inputValue: String): Double => Double = {
  if (inputValue == "Lower") _ * 0.85
  else identity
}
```

The rewritten versions are more efficient, because the `if` does not have to be evaluated every time. The last version might even be a bit clearer, because the `identity`-function is written down as one non-simplifiable "thing" that can be returned.